# Why is the C++ initializer_list behavior for std::vector and std::array different?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Code:

```
std::vector<int> x{1,2,3,4};
std::array<int, 4> y{{1,2,3,4}};
```

Why do I need double curly braces for std::array?

Comment: Do you actually need the second set of braces for `std::array`, or are you just getting a warning? `std::array<int,4> y{1,2,3,4};` works for me.

Comment: @bames53: GCC is wrong in compiling that.

Comment: @Xeo: it's not "wrong" to compile an ill-formed program with a warning.

Comment: @Steve: True that. Let's say non-portable?

Comment: @Xeo: yeah, I use `-Werror` anyway for code I've written, so it doesn't harm my portability any. Others' mileage may vary, if they're lightweights or need to include header files written by lightweights :-)

Comment: @bames53: yes it also works for me.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`std::array<T, N>` is an aggregate:  it doesn't have any user-declared constructors, not even one taking a `std::initializer_list`.  Initialization using braces is performed using *aggregate initialization*, a feature of C++ that was inherited from C.

The "old style" of aggregate initialization uses the `=`:

```
std::array<int, 4> y = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

With this old style of aggregate initialization, extra braces may be elided, so this is equivalent to:

```
std::array<int, 4> y = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

However, these extra braces may only be elided "in a declaration of the form `T x = { a };`" (C++11 §8.5.1/11), that is, when the old style `=` is used .  This rule allowing brace elision does not apply for direct list initialization.  A footnote here reads:  "Braces cannot be elided in other uses of list-initialization."

There is a defect report concerning this restriction: [CWG defect #1270](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3367.html#1270).  If the proposed resolution is adopted, brace elision will be allowed for other forms of list initialization, and the following will be well-formed:

```
std::array<int, 4> y{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

(Hat tip to Ville Voutilainen for finding the defect report.)

Comment: So it's a failure of the abstraction model being presented for `array`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It *is* uniform. What *isn't* uniform is the fact that you're initializing two completely different types.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I thought the whole point of uniformity was to use the same initialization syntax for different types? (Yes, I do understand what's happening... I'm just saying it's not "uniform" to the user, regardless of whether there's an explanation for it.)

Comment: @MarkRansom: Well, it's rather a quirk of the language, because `std::array<int> y = {1,2,3,4};` works with a *warning* from Clang *suggesting* braces, instead of a hard error about not being allowed to "omit braces around initialization of subobject when using direct list-initialization".

Comment: @Xeo:  Actually, brace elision is permitted in aggregate initialization, but (apparently) not when the direct list initialization syntax is used.

Comment: However, the standard doesn't say anything about array having a single data member of type T[N]. In fact, to me it seems to imply that it should behave like an aggregate of `N` elements, not an aggregate containing a single element (see §23.3.2.1).

Comment: @juanchopanza:  The specification says that it is an aggregate and that it "can be initialized with the syntax `array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };` where _initializer-list_ is a comma-separated list of up to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`."  An implementation with a single data member of type `T[N]` (as demonstrated in the exposition in the specification), would meet this requirement, but would apparently not be initializable via the direct list initializer.

Answer (score 34):

Because `std::vector` offers a constructor that takes in a `std::initializer_list<T>`, while `std::array` has no constructors and the `{1, 2, 3, 4}` braced init-list is in fact not interpreted as a `std::initializer_list`, but aggregate initialization for the inner C-style array of `std::array` (that's where the second set of braces comes from: One for `std::array`, one for the inner C-style member array).