# When can outer braces be omitted in an initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I've got error C2078 in VC2010 when compiling the code below.

```
struct A
  {
  int foo;
  double bar;
  };

std::array<A, 2> a1 = 
  // error C2078: too many initializers
  {
    {0, 0.1},
    {2, 3.4}
  };

// OK
std::array<double, 2> a2 = {0.1, 2.3};
```

I found out that the correct syntax for `a1` is

```
std::array<A, 2> a1 = 
  {{
    {0, 0.1},
    {2, 3.4}
  }};
```

The question is: why extra braces are required for `a1` but not required for `a2`?

**Update**

The question seems to be not specific to std::array. Some examples:

```
struct B
  {
  int foo[2];
  };

// OK
B meow1 = {1,2};
B bark1 = {{1,2}};

struct C
  {
  struct 
    { 
    int a, b; 
    } foo;
  };

// OK
C meow2 = {1,2};
C bark2 = {{1,2}};

struct D
  {
  struct 
    { 
    int a, b; 
    } foo[2];
  };

D meow3 = {{1,2},{3,4}};  // error C2078: too many initializers
D bark3 = {{{1,2},{3,4}}};
```

I still don't see why `struct D` gives the error but B and C don't.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That will not work! See my answer to know the reason.

Comment: @Nawaz: Then why does it work for `double`? Aren't you allowed to collapse braces under certain conditions? Or maybe that was only true for multi-dimensional arrays...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Because `double` is not an aggregate, while `A` is. In other words, `std::array<double, 2>` is an aggregate of aggregate, while `std::array<A, 2>` is an aggregate of aggregate of aggregate!

Comment: @Nawaz: But note that the OP can do the `double` array with *one* pair of braces, as opposed to *three* for the `A` type. We're still one pair short!

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think that extra braces is still needed in case of `double` also, to be completely the Standard conformant, but it works without it. It seems I need to dig the spec again!

Comment: @Nawaz: A fully standard-conformant syntax for a2 is `std::array<double, 2> a2 = {{0.1, 2.3}};`, but I wonder too why it's allowed to omit one pair of braces.

Comment: @Andrey: That is what I said. +1

Comment: Just as a speculation, std::array might have an operator= that takes an std::initializer_list?

Comment: @fish: certainly not the case in VC2010

Comment: @fish no, std::array is an aggregate, so it can have no such constructor. The problem is that it may be implemented as having a single array as element, which is why the extra braces are required.

Comment: There is an interesting, related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/c-why-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-are-different).

Comment: @Andrey: See the edit/quote in my answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The extra braces are needed because `std::array` is an [aggregate and Plain Old Datatype (POD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-trivial-types-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special), unlike other containers in the standard library. `std::array` doesn't have a user-defined constructor. Its first data member is an array of size `N` (which you pass as a template argument), and this member is directly initialized with an initializer. The extra braces are needed for the *internal* array which is being directly initialized.

The situation is same as:

```
//define this aggregate - no user-defined constructor
struct Aarray
{
   A data[2];  //data is an internal array
};
```

How would you initialize this? If you do this:

```
Aarray a1 =
{
   {0, 0.1},
   {2, 3.4}
};
```

it gives a [compilation error](https://ideone.com/z0ky3):

> error: too many initializers for 'Aarray'

This is the *same* error which you get in the case of a `std::array` (if you use GCC).

So the correct thing to do is to use *braces* as follows:

```
Aarray a1 =
{
  {  //<--this tells the compiler that initialization of `data` starts

        { //<-- initialization of `data[0]` starts

           0, 0.1

        }, //<-- initialization of `data[0]` ends

       {2, 3.4}  //initialization of data[1] starts and ends, as above

  } //<--this tells the compiler that initialization of `data` ends
};
```

which [compiles fine](https://ideone.com/t7AdR). Once again, the extra braces are needed because you're initializing the *internal* array.

--

Now the question is why are extra braces not needed in case of `double`?

<strike>It is because `double` is not an aggregate, while `A` is. In other words, `std::array<double, 2>` is an aggregate of aggregate, while `std::array<A, 2>` is an aggregate of aggregate of aggregate<sup>1</sup>.</strike>

<sup>1. I think that extra braces are still needed in the case of double also (like [this](https://ideone.com/wZkeo)), to be completely conformant to the Standard, but the code works without them. It seems I need to dig through the spec again!</sup>.

#More on braces and extra braces

I dug through the spec. This section (§8.5.1/11 from C++11) is interesting and applies to this case:

> In a declaration of the form

```
T x = { a };
```

> **braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows**. If the initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the members of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more initializer-clauses than members. If, however, the initializer-list for a subaggregate
> does not begin with a left brace, then only enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the members of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is a member. [ Example:

```
float y[4][3] = {
{ 1, 3, 5 },
{ 2, 4, 6 },
{ 3, 5, 7 },
};
```

> is a completely-braced initialization: 1, 3, and 5 initialize the first row of the array `y[0]`, namely `y[0][0]`, `y[0][1]`, and `y[0][2]`. Likewise the next two lines initialize `y[1]` and `y[2]`. The initializer ends early and therefore `y[3]s` elements are initialized as if explicitly initialized with an expression of the form float(), that is, are initialized with 0.0. In the following example, braces in the initializer-list are elided; however the initializer-list has the same effect as the completely-braced initializer-list of the above example,

```
float y[4][3] = {
1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7
};
```

> The initializer for y begins with a left brace, but the one for `y[0]` does not, therefore three elements from the list are used. Likewise the next three are taken successively for `y[1]` and `y[2]`. —end example ]

Based on what I understood from the above quote, I can say that the following should be allowed:

```
//OKAY. Braces are completely elided for the inner-aggregate
std::array<A, 2> X =   
{
  0, 0.1,
  2, 3.4
};

//OKAY. Completely-braced initialization
std::array<A, 2> Y = 
{{
   {0, 0.1},
   {2, 3.4}
}};
```

In the first one, braces for the inner-aggregate are completely elided, while the second has fully-braced initialization. In your case (the case of `double`), the initialization uses the first approach (braces are *completely* elided for the inner aggregate).

But this should be disallowed:

```
//ILL-FORMED : neither braces-elided, nor fully-braced
std::array<A, 2> Z = 
{
  {0, 0.1},
  {2, 3.4}
};
```

It is neither braces-elided, nor are there enough braces to be completely-braced initialization. Therefore, it is ill-formed.

Comment: An interesting, related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/c-why-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-are-different). To me it is not clear at all that the array **has** to be implemented as a single-element aggregate. The standard provides an example implementation to emphasize that it is an aggregate, but I see no requirement that it be implemented so (although I cannot currently think of an alternative implementation).

Comment: Great answer! Just found more compilable initializers for `struct D` from the question: `D d1 = {1,2,3,4};
D d2 = {{1,2,3,4}};`

Comment: For those not clicking the link @juanchopanza posted, there is link to an [official defect report](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3367.html#1270) about the brace elision limitation.

Comment: It is not necessary for a type to be a POD for brace elision to apply. Furthermore, something like `std::array<std::string>` is plainly *not* a POD.