# Range-based loop & Inline functions

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, inline

I have here this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> inline T bigArry(const T data[5])
{
    T level = data[0];
    for(T item : data) // error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':' (1st)
    { //error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' (3rd)
        if(level<item){ level=item; }
    }
    return  level;
}

int main()
{
    int data[5]={//five variables}
    cout << bigArry(data);//see reference to function template instantiation 'T bigArry<int>(const T [])' being compiled with [ T=int] (2nd)

    return 0;
}
```

The function bigArry() returns the highest value out of a array of 5 elements.

The problem is that when I use the range-based loop it gives me the errors mentioned in the code. But when I use the usual for, everything goes back to normal.
I mean, the syntax to me looks fine, I can't see the problem.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

The other thing I want to ask is about the inline functions. Currently I'm reading C++ Primer Plus 6th edition. When do I know when a function is too big to be inlined? Is there a standard of how short the code should be? Or, do we use the inline functions when we "think" it's okay?

Comment: Shouldn't your 2nd compiler error have `[ T=int ]`, instead of `float`?

Comment: How about using `vector<T>`?

Comment: The float comes from the old array I've declared.

Comment: @RobertEagle: I figured. But you might want to edit it to avoid some possible confusion.

Comment: Visual Studo 2010 doesn't support c++11 ranged base for loops? it only has a older custom syntax "for (T item in data) {}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter `data` is NOT an array in your function template. It is actually a pointer.

This function

```
template <typename T> inline T bigArry(const T data[5])
```

is *exactly* same as this:

```
template <typename T> inline T bigArry(const T *data)
```

**There is NO difference at all.**

That is the reason why your code gives compilation error.

There're couple of fixes here:

- You could accept the argument by reference, as:

  ```
  template <typename T> 
  inline T bigArry(const T (&data)[5]) //NOTE &
  ```

  That should work.   But then that looks cumbersome. Maybe, use the next.
- Or you could use this (as suggested by @yzt):

  ```
  template <typename C> 
  inline auto bigArry(C const & data) -> decltype(data[0])
  ```

  This is clean as well as more flexible than the above one (and the below one). In addition to passing arrays, you could pass *any* container as long as `data[0]` is well-defined and means what it supposed to mean.
- Or if you wish, you could use `std::array<T, 5>` as:

  ```
  template <typename T> 
  inline T bigArry(const std::array<T,5> & data)
  ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe this signature will work with plain C arrays and some other containers, including `std::vector`s and `std::array`s, and is more permissive in size of arrays that is accepts: `template <typename C> inline decltype(C[0]) bigArry(C const & data)`

Comment: I suggest it here (instead of in another answer) for you to add it to your answer, if you see fit. I think it's a better answer than using `std::array` as it doesn't require a new header. But it's certainly more "cumbersome".

Comment: @yzt: Done. (BTW, `decltype(C[0])` doesn't mean anything; what you meant is called trailing-return-type).

Comment: Oh, right! What I meant to write was `decltype(C()[0])`, but that's incorrect too. The correct way, as you point out, is a trailing `-> decltype(data[0])`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

That is because array types decay to pointers when used as function parameters or when passed as function argument. In other words, **your function signature is equivalent to**:

```
template <typename T> inline T bigArry(const T* data)
```

The range-based `for` loop passes `data` to the global `std::begin()` and `std::end()` functions in order to get iterators to (respectively) the first and the one-past-the-last element of the container.

Of course, there are no global `std::begin()` and `std::end()` functions that accept a *pointer*, and they couldn't be meaningfully defined either: how to determine the end of the container given just a pointer to its first element?

You can use `std::array` instead of C arrays (`std::array` is a zero-overhead wrapper around a C array), and modify your calling function accordingly:

```
template <typename T> inline T bigArry(std::array<T, 5> data)
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    T level = data[0];
    for(T item : data)
    {
        if(level<item){ level=item; }
    }
    return  level;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> data = {1,2,3,4,5};
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::cout << bigArry(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=077762de7ca7140694e66912bfce7e6c-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3).

Comment: I believe this signature will work with plain C arrays and some other containers, including `std::vector`s and `std::array`s: `template <typename C> inline decltype(C[0]) bigArry(C const & data) {...}`

Comment: @Andy: Actually [the rules for the curly-braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list) are a bit confusing at times. But what I said before doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: I'm using the curly-braces that way so I can work with the concept that everything is clustered. It's easier for me.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I suggest it here (instead of in my own answer) for you to add it to your answer, if you see fit. I think it's a better solution than using `std::array` as it doesn't require a new header.

Comment: By the way, I made a mistake in my first comment (as pointed out by @Nawaz in another answer's comment section.) The hopefully correct way is `template <typename C> inline auto bigArry(C const & data) -> decltype(data[0]) {...}`.