# Can we omit the double-braces for std::array in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm reading through the draft standard for C++14 right now, and perhaps my legalese is a bit rusty, but I can't find any mention of allowing initializations like the following

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{1,2,3};
```

being legal. (EDIT: Apparently the above is legal syntax in C++11.) Currently in C++11 we have to initialize std::array as

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{{1,2,3}}; // uniform initialization + aggregate initialization
```

or

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {1,2,3};
```

I thought I heard somewhere that they were relaxing the rules in C++14 so that we didn't have to use the double-brace method when using uniform initialization, but I can't find the actual proof.

NOTE: The reason I care about this is because I am currently developing a multi_array - type and don't want to have to initialize it like

```
multi_array<int, 2, 2> matrix = {
  {{ 1, 2 }}, {{ 3, 4 }}
};
```

Comment: note: this discussion only applies to array of scalar type;  for arrays of aggregates [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541488/nested-aggregate-initialization-of-stdarray)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can outer braces be omitted in an initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually you can write the following in C++11 also:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr{1,2,3};
```

It is completely valid syntax.

What is **not** allowed in C++11 though is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list) case *(see that topic; I don't want to write this here again, it is a long post)*. So if you ask that then, yes, we can omit the extra braces in C++14. This is the proposal:

- [Uniform initialization for arrays and class aggregate types](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3526.html)
- The introduction says

  > This document proposes a **slight relaxation of the rules for eliding braces** from aggregate initialization in order to make initialization of arrays and class aggregates more uniform. This change is required in order to support class aggregate types with a single member subaggregate that behave similarly to their array counterparts (i.e. `std::array`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Looking forward to when I can use it, now :-)

Comment: The [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) says that `std::array<int, 3> arr{1,2,3};` is not valid in C++11.  (it may be wrong)

Comment: The 'this case' topic you link says, like cppreference, that `std::array <int, 3> arr{1,2,3}` is **not** valid syntax in C++11, as the rules were relaxed only in C++14.

Comment: That proposal was never adopted.  Instead, the preexisting brace elision rules [were generalized](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3367.html#1270) to support this case.