# Nested aggregate initialization of std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++14, aggregate-initialization

I wonder, why declaration of `std_arr` in the following code generates an error, while `c_arr` compiles well:

```
struct S { int a, b; };

S c_arr[] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};  // OK
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};  // Error: too many initializers
```

Both `std::array` and `S` are aggregates. From [aggregate initialization on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list (which is not an expression and has no type), the corresponding class member is
>   itself an aggregate: aggregate initialization is recursive.

Why this initialization of `std::array` does not compile?

Comment: It should be `std::array<S, 2> std_arr{{ {1, 2}, {3, 4} }};` - outer ones surrounding constructor arguments, next pair for the initialiser list, inner pairs for each `S` element.  C++14 will make it work with one less set of outer `{ }`.  (The `=` is optional.)

Comment: @remyabel The rules of aggregate initialisation changed between C++11 and C++14, IIRC, and it's not clear to me that they aren't relevant here.

Comment: @hvd No changes regarding brace elision, though.

Comment: You say : "hey I read the std and it says I should be able to do X, but when i do my compiler cries". Don't you think it might be relevant to specify the compiler and the version you are using ?

Comment: @T.C. I wasn't sure about that, but I'll take your word for that.

Comment: @hvd According to cppreference, the C++14 change has to do with brace elision with a brace-or-equal initializer. However, I can't get it to error in C++11 mode in GCC or Clang, but otherwise, I think the answer to OP's question should be the same for both C++11 or C++14.

Comment: @remyabel Ah, and the answer to that almost-duplicate gives the answer: brace elision didn't change between C++11 and C++14, but it did change in a post-C++11 DRs that should be taken to apply to C++11. So it's correct that you don't see a difference in compilers with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`: that DR resolution is applied even in C++11 mode. Aside from that, it covers `std::array<S, 2> std_arr {1, 2, 3, 4};` without the `=`, so it's not relevant to this particular question anyway. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The braces in aggregate initialisation are largely optional, so you can write:

```
S c_arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};  // OK
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};  // OK
```

If you do add braces, though, then the braces are taken to apply to the next sub-object. Unfortunately, when you start nesting, this leads to silly code being valid, and sensible code like yours being invalid.

```
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};  // OK
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {1, 2, {3, 4}};  // OK
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {1, {2}, {3, 4}};  // OK
```

These are all okay. `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is a valid initialiser for the `S[2]` member of `std_arr`. `{2}` is okay because it is an attempt to initialise an `int`, and `{2}` is a valid initialiser for that. `{3, 4}` is taken as an initialiser for `S`, and it's also valid for that.

```
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};  // error
```

This is not okay because `{1, 2}` is taken as a valid initialiser for the `S[2]` member. The remaining `int` sub-objects are initialised to zero.

You then have `{3, 4}`, but there are no more members to initialise.

As pointed out in the comments,

```
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
```

also works. The nested `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` is an initialiser for the `S[2]` member. The `{1, 2}` is an initialiser for the first `S` element. The `{3, 4}` is an initialiser for the second `S` element.

<sub>I'm assuming here that `std::array<S, 2>` contains an array member of type `S[2]`, which it does on current implementations, and which I believe is likely to become guaranteed, but which has been covered on SO before and is not currently guaranteed.</sub>

Comment: I see it now. Logical, but very non-obvious. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to omit initializers for `b`; e.g. `std::array<S, 2> g = { {1}, {3} };` hoping to get `g[1].a == 3` ... then it seems all of the weird suggestions are unusable and double-bracing is the only option.  So much for C++14 supposedly not requiring double-bracing for `std::array` ...

Comment: Once more an example how uniform initialisation is flawed... I personally would clearly prefer classic constructor syntax `std::array<S, 2> std_arr({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});` with parentheses...

Answer (score 4):

Since the question is tagged C++14, I'll be quoting N4140. In [array] it says that `std::array` is an aggregate:

> 2 An `array` is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax
>
> ```
>   array a = { initializer-list };
> ```
>
> where *initializer-list* is a comma-separated list of up to `N` elements
>   whose types are convertible to `T`.

In general, it's agreed that you need an extra pair of outer braces to initialize the underlying aggregate, which looks something like `T elems[N]`. In paragraph 3, it's explained that this is for exposition purposes and not actually part of the interface. In practice, however, libstdc++ and Clang implement it like that:

```
  template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
    struct __array_traits
    {
      typedef _Tp _Type[_Nm];

      static constexpr _Tp&
      _S_ref(const _Type& __t, std::size_t __n) noexcept
      { return const_cast<_Tp&>(__t[__n]); }
    };

  template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
    struct array
    {
      /* Snip */

      // Support for zero-sized arrays mandatory.
      typedef _GLIBCXX_STD_C::__array_traits<_Tp, _Nm> _AT_Type;
      typename _AT_Type::_Type                         _M_elems;
```

Clang:

```
template <class _Tp, size_t _Size>
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY array
{
    /* Snip */

    value_type __elems_[_Size > 0 ? _Size : 1];
```

There are changes between C++11 and C++14 regarding aggregate initialization, however none that would make:

```
std::array<S, 2> std_arr = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

not ill-formed.