# How to properly aggregate-initialize nested std::array?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

I have a very simple structure that looks like this:

```cpp
struct Arr
{
    static constexpr auto width = 2;
    static constexpr auto height = 2;
    std::array<std::array<int, width>, height> values;
};
```

How do I properly initialize this structure without getting compiler errors or warnings?
I tried the following ([see example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sbM4GMKE8)):

```cpp
auto arr = Arr{1, 2, 3, 4}; // clang: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
auto arr = Arr{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; // clang: error: excess elements in struct initializer
auto arr = Arr{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}; // clang: error: excess elements in struct initializer
```

I know there have been similar questions asked (e.g. [Nested aggregate initialization of std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541488/nested-aggregate-initialization-of-stdarray)), but it seems all of them focus on C++11/14.

Comment: Not sure this is the same issue, but Clang lags behind on aggregate initialization

Comment: gcc accepts 1), but warns in 2) and errors in 3)

Comment: both gcc and clang seem to accept `Arr { {{ {{1,2}}, {{3,4}} }} };` with no warnings. (Each std::array level uses a double set of braces).

Comment: I think I fell one brace-pair short of that when I was trying things out, so thanks for the tip. But anyway, are these just quirks of the compilers, or is there anything in the standard that mandates this brace proliferation?

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the standard that mandates this. If you need a bulletproof method, say `{ std::array{std::array{1,2}, std::array{3,4}} };`.