# How to initialize an array easily in constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization

How to initialize an array easily in the constructor? For example

```
class A
{
    array<array<int, 2>, 2> m;
    A(int m00, int m01, int m10, int m11)
       : m {m00, m01, m10, m11} // ??? how to list here 
    {}
};
```

Comment: It works as is if you fix the variable typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> m;
    A(int m00, int m01, int m10, int m11)
       : m {{{m00, m01}, {m10, m11}}}
    {}
};
```

Comment: I intuitively understand `{m00, m01}` for inner array, and `{{...}, {...}}` for outer, but why are the outermost braces needed?

Comment: I think the answer is right. but why need 3 pairs of `{}`? If it is `vector<vector<int>>`, need 3 sets also?

Comment: @user1899020 In short, because `array` is an aggregate. Because inner type is an aggregate itself, you actually can drop all braces, except outer ones: `m{m00, m01, m10, m11}`

Comment: @user1899020 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792731/can-we-omit-the-double-braces-for-stdarray-in-c14

Comment: Maybe `initializer_list` is better?