# Initializer-list for initializing 2D std::array member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

How to initialize a nested (2D) `std::array` via an initializer-list?

```
template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
class Block
{
    std::array<std::array<int, W>, H> block;
public:

    template <typename ...E>
    Block(E&&...e) : block {{std::forward<E>(e)...}} {}
};
```

The class `Block` should able  to initialize `block` member as below:

```
Block<3, 2> b {{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }};
```

---

Note: We have the ability to initialize the `std::array` directly in C++11:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> b {{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }};
```

I'm using gcc-4.9.0

Comment: By making `block` private and providing a ctor, `Block` now isn't an aggregate any more. As braced-initializers are never deduced from, the only valid initialized for an object of type `Block<3,2>` now is `Block<3,2> b {1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Comment: Roll this back to the revision that makes sense for the answers, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for braces are very complicated when it comes to nested structures.

The simplest form in your code would be this:

```
Block<3, 2> b {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

That basically omits all the inner braces — these omissions are allowed by the language.

The next syntax, which is slightly complex, is this:

```
Block<3, 2> b {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
```

It still omits braces, but as far as `Block` and as its member is concerned it is FULLY braced. It omits braces for the `array` and its members.

And this one is FULLY braced:

```
Block<3, 2> b {{{ {{1, 2,3}}, {{4,5,6}} }}};
```

It braces for all inner structures.

[All forms compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6967cccdf32244d).

See my other answer for detailed explanation:

- [When can outer braces be omitted in an initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)

Answer (score 1):

It may be to do with the interpretation of the standard being overly capricious with the number of braces required to initialize `std::array`. This fully braced version compiles without issues on GCC 4.8.1:

```
Block<3, 2> b {
               {
                { 
                 { {1, 2, 3} }, { {4, 5, 6} } 
                }
               }
              };
```

Strangely, this version compiles too:

```
  Block<3, 2> b { 
                 {{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} } }
                };
```

Comment: @MM. No problem. It still doesn't make any sense to me. Anyway, I think your first attempt should be legal in C++14.