# Too many initializers for Array error

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have implemented following structures:

```
struct Point {
    int x,y;
};

struct Array {
    Point elem[3];
};
```

Could you explain why I'm getting an error:

> error: too many initializers for 'Array'

when I use following construction?:

```
Array points2 {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need more braces, since you're initialising objects within an array within a class:

```
Array points2 { { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};
              ^ ^ ^
              | | |
              | | array element
              | array
              class
```

Answer (score 7):

You actually need one more set of braces like so:

```
Array points2 {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/GBHEaK)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list) for further explanation of when these extra braces are required. It is related to whether the container is an aggregate or not.