# How can I create an std::array of char array?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to create a std::array of char array so that I could declare it static constexpr.

eg:

```
#include <array>

int main(){

  static constexpr char A[] = "abc";
  static constexpr char B[] = "def";
  static constexpr std::array<char[], 3> tmp{A, B};
}
```

When I do this I get error message " too many initializers for"

Comment: There is no `std::array` in your code

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26629609/10077.

Comment: @tkausl updated

Comment: @DanielLangr Sorry it was supposed to be A and B.

Comment: char[]  here seem to be an invalid use for std::array

Comment: @DanielLangr I changed value of 
both A and B to be size 3.. still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By output of your compiler I could surmise that you have a non-standard extension active. Stricly ISO-wise use of char[] as parameter of template is not legal,. Some compilers would treat that as char[0].

what your array meant to store? way you're trying to do it would store adresses of array to char (and only way to do so would be replace `char[]` by by `const char*` in template parameters. `std::array` is trivial class  which stores data statically so you cannot implement array with variable length of strings that way.

Either 1)  abolish constexpr and use `std::string`  2) use `const char*` 3) worst case (which sometimes is the best) - use fixed array length or "naked" 2-dimensional array with aggregate initializer list.

Comment: When I said it to store char[] why is std::array trying to store address? shouldn't it store char[]?

Comment: @mike depends on which compiler you use. judging by output of yours it was treating char[] as char[0] and is unable to store literals you give it. One I used was saying that char[] is illegal, and it is by ISO standard. so 1) store addresses 2) store string classes 3) store arrays of fixed length. actually can use std::array instead of char[x]

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
static constexpr std::array<char[4], 2> tmp {{{ A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3] },
                                              { B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3] }}};
```

or

```
static constexpr std::array<char[4], 2> tmp { "abc", "def" };
```

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array:

> When initializing an object of array type, the initializer must be either a string literal (optionally enclosed in braces) or be a brace-enclosed list of initialized for array members.

Thus you cannot initialize an array (member of `std::array` of `char[4]`) by an object of another array.

Answer (score 0):

With C++20 `std::to_array` can be used.

```
static constexpr char A[] = "abc";
static constexpr char B[] = "def";
static constexpr auto tmp = std::to_array({A, B});
```