# Is it correct to initialize std::array by one pair of curly brackets if zeroed array needed?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I wonder if this construction:

```
std::array<int, 10> array { };
```

is equivalent to this:

```
std::array<int, 10> array { {  } };
```

Well, both of them compile and both of them give the same result:

```
for (auto e : array) {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

Out:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

I know that to initialize std::array by selected values I must use double curly brackets because of aggregate initialization. But I don't know how it behaves with single brackets. So, the question is:

Is this totally correct to initialize struct by single curly brackets in C++11? (this follows that all field of struct will be zeroed)

Edit:
As @dyp noted my question in post is more general. Let's assume that my question is about structs with only trivial elements.

Comment: *"Is this total correct to initialize struct by single curly brackets..."* Is a much more general and more difficult question than *"Is it correct to initializing std::array by one pair of curly brackets if zeroed array needed?*"

Comment: Yes, that's fine (for `std::array`). You shouldn't have to use double curly brackets either; `std::array<int, 10> arr = {1, 2, 3};` is required to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everything is now clear.

Comment: This explains a lot...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list

I believe this changed in C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.5.1 Aggregates)

> 7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equalinitializer, from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4).

and (8.5.4 List-initialization p.#3)

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is
>   value-initialized.

Thus initializations

```
std::array<int, 10> array {};
```

and

```
std::array<int, 10> array { {  } };
```

are equivalent.

Comment: Except that GCC emits a `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning about the former.