# Initialize aggregate as class member

Tags: c++, list-initialization

In this code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

struct K {
    std::array<char, 4> a;
    std::uint8_t b;
};

const K k1 = { {'T', 'e', 's', 't'}, 1 };

class X {
    const K k2 = { {'A', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, 2 };
};
```

I can initialize a global object `k1` just fine.  But trying to use the same syntax on a default initializer of the class member `k2` gives compiler errors (similar errors from g++-4.8.2 and g++-5.2.0):

```
main.cpp:12:44: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     const K k2 = { {'A', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, 2 };
                                            ^
main.cpp:12:44: error: too many initializers for 'std::array<char, 4ul>'
```

What's the correct way to initialize `k2` at its declaration?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Clang accepts it with warning `main.cpp:9:17: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]` (for `std::array` initialization).

Comment: [When can outer braces be omitted in an initializer list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an extra pair of braces:

```
class X {
    const K k2 = { {{'A', 'b', 'c', 'd'}}, 2 };
};
```

Comment: I find it amusing that uniform initialisation is no such thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit More fun on the way, hold on for C++17 :)

Comment: Is this a Standard requirement, or is g++ bugged to not accept the original?

Comment: @M.M I think that this was a requirement until C++14. I'm not aware if GCC conforms on this matter or not.