# What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector<MyClass> with hardcoded elements?

Tags: c++, initialization

I wish to create a vector of MyClass, like the following Course class.
and I wish to pass an array of string as the names of Courses. So I write

```
struct Course {
    int id;
    string name;
    static int id_generator;

    Course() {}
    Course(string s);

};

Course::Course(string s) {
    name = s;
    id = id_generator++;
}
int Course::id_generator = 0;
```

This works

```
string course_names[] = {"Linux", "C++", "HTML", "HTML5", "NodeJS", "Shell", "Python"};
vector<Course> course_vector(begin(course_names), end(course_names));
```

but this doesn't

```
vector<Course> course_vector = {"Linux", "C++", "HTML", "HTML5", "NodeJS", "Shell", "Python"};

error: could not convert ‘{"Linux", "C++", "HTML", "HTML5", "NodeJS", "Shell", "Python"}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<Course>’
```

why? how to do better?

Comment: Another option is `vector<Course> course_vector = {"Linux"s, "C++"s, "HTML"s};`

Comment: using ctor-initializer for `name` is better than default-construction followed by assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregate initialization used for aggregate types as arrays:

```
string course_names[] = {"Linux", "C++", "HTML", "HTML5", "NodeJS", "Shell", "Python"};
```

Is different to `initializer_list` initialization. `std::vector` offers a constructor that takes in a `std::initializer_list<T>`, and that's the constructor called when you try to initialize a `vector` with braces. For this to work properly, you need extra braces for each element:

```
std::vector<Course> course_vector = {{"Linux"}, 
                                     {"C++"},
                                     {"HTML"},
                                     {"HTML5"},
                                     {"NodeJS"},
                                     {"Shell"},
                                     {"Python"}};
```

Also I it would be better to change your constructor to:

```
Course::Course(std::string const &s) : id(id_generator++),  name(s) { }
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a996d1f2218f95d8)

Comment: so what do extra braces means ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)'s a really good explanation of omission of outer braces for interested readers.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following constructor:

```
Course::Course(const char *s) : name(s) {
    id = id_generator++;
}
```

This way, you will be able to initialize the vector directly, just like you wanted.

Comment: well that or do `vector<Course> course_vector = {"Linux"s, "C++"s, "HTML"s, "HTML5"s};` if he has a compiler with `std::string` literal support

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++11 or up you can do something like this

```
std::vector<Course> vec = {Course("course1"), Course("course2"), Course("course3")};
```