# Declarring multidimensional std::arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the first time that I am going to use a multidimensional std::array. 
I want to declare 9 matrix of  3 x 3  dimensions.

In a conventional c++ array we declare like the following.

int a[9][3][3];

When I try to declare this array using std::array the sequence of dimensions is upside down, It must be declared like the following.

```
array<array<array<int, 3>, 3, 9)
```

my expectation was to declare that matrix like we declare the conventional arrays like the following.

```
  array<array<array<int, 9>, 3, 3)
```

There is no documentation on this matter.
What is the C++ standard

Comment: *"I want to declare 9 matrix of 3 x 3 dimensions."* Then the first way you wrote it is correct, not the last way (except you're missing some `>` for your template params)

Comment: `array<array<array<int, 3>, 3, 9)` This works? Shouldn't it be `array<array<array<int, 3>, 3>,  9>`?

Comment: What about doing it in two steps? First `using matrix = array<array<int, 3>, 3>;` and then `array<matrix, 9>`.

Comment: Each `<`  needs to be matched with a `>`.   So it is not `array<array<array<int, 9>, 3, 3)` (like you have), it is `array<array<array<int, 9>, 3>, 3>`.   Depending on order of indices you need (you haven't specified), you may need to adjust to `array<array<array<int, 3>, 3>, 9>`

Comment: What is there to document? An `array<T, N>` is a length N array of `T`. That is all you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

Use `>` instead of `)` :

```
using matrices = array<array<array<int,3>,3>,9>;
```

And you can write, as suggested in the comments:

```
// N is number of rows, M number of columns
template<int N, int M>
using matrix = array<array<int,N>,M>;

using matrices = array<matrix<3,3>,9>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Why can't simple initialize (with braces) 2D std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/why-cant-simple-initialize-with-braces-2d-stdarray)

Try `std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>, 9> myArray;`.

Remember to `#include<array>`.