# Why can't a 2D std::array be initialized with two layers of list-initializers?

Tags: c++, stdarray, list-initialization

can someone help me understand why my compiler can't/doesn't deduce this? (using g++ 7.3)

Does not work:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
 return {{0,0},{0,0}};
}
```

Works fine:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
 return {std::array<double,2>{0,0},{0,0}};
}
```

Also weirdly this fails too:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
 return std::array<std::array<double,2>,2>{{0,0},{0,0}};
}
```

@1201ProgramAlarm pointed out that adding another set of curly braces works:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
 return {{{0,0},{0,0}}};
}
```

It's using aggregate initialization, because `std::array` has no constructor for brace-init-list. That's fine, but then why/how does this work?

```
std::array<double,2> x{1,2};
```

why does it handle this case but not the nested case?

Comment: What about the size? you have not defined the size of outer array. That may be causing the problem.

Comment: You need [another set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/why-is-the-c-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-differen) of curly braces.

Comment: By the way, why not use `typedef double mat[2][2];`?

Comment: Very close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/why-cant-simple-initialize-with-braces-2d-stdarray

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container `std::array` is equivalently a struct holding a C-array (an implementation may not implement `std::array` in this way, but it should guarantee the semantic is the same), so it should be initialized by two layers of braces, i.e.

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
   return {{{{0,0}},{{0,0}}}};
}
```

Of course, braces in an initializer-list can be elided like what we usually do for a 2D array:

```
int arr[2][2] = {0,1,2,3};
```

... but the initializer-list that begins with the elided braces before the elision should not begin with a left brace after the elision. In other words, if an initializer-list begins with a left brace, the compiler will not consider the possibility that this initializer-list has elided outermost braces.

In your initializer `{{0,0},{0,0}}`, the sub-initializer `{0,0},{0,0}` begins with a left brace, so it is used to initialize the C-array itself. However, there are two clauses in the list while there is only one C-array, an error occurs.

In your initializer `{std::array<double,2>{0,0},{0,0}}`, the sub-initializer `std::array<double,2>{0,0},{0,0}` does not begin with a left brace, so it can be used to initialize the elements of the C-array, which is OK (recursively, `{0,0}` is OK to initialize an `std::array<double,2>` because the sub-initializer `0,0` does not begin with a left brace).

---

A suggestion: with this elision rule of braces, you can elide all inner braces, just like what we usually do for a 2D array:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<double,2>,2> f() {
   return {0,0,0,0};
}
```