# how to initialize 2D array from initializer_list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

```
typedef unsigned char u8;

template <u8 N>
class matrix {
    public:
        matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>& l);
    private:
        std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> arr;
};

template <u8 N>
matrix<N>::matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>& l) : arr(l) {}
```

> error C2664:
>   'std::array,2>::array(std::array,2>
>   &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const
>   std::initializer_list>' to 'const
>   std::array,2> &'

How do I initialize 2D `std::array` (or C array for that matter) from 2D `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: The simple way would be to not to.  Have a `std::array<int, N * N>` as the class member and pretend that it has multiple dimensions.

Comment: Though I want my initialization to look proper `matrix<2> m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};` and not `matrix<2> m = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

Comment: I don't think you can do aggregate initialization once *it* becomes `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is an aggregate.  That means you can initialize it from a *braced-init-list* like

```
std::array<int, 4> foo = {1,2,3,4};
```

In your constructor though you don't *braced-init-list*, you have a `std::initlizer_list`, which cannot be used to initialize a `std::array`.  What you would have to do is copy the data from the `std::initlizer_list` into the array like

```
template <u8 N>
matrix<N>::matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> l)
{
    u8 counter = 0;
    for (auto row : l)
        std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), arr[counter++].begin());
}
```

Also note that you don't have to pass the by `std::initlizer_list` reference.    It is a lightweight object and passing by value is fine, it wont copy the underlying elements.

---

You could change you class to take a the 2d array as a parameter so you can directly initialize `arr` with that but because of [how you have to initialize aggregates of aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/why-cant-simple-initialize-with-braces-2d-stdarray) you get into curly brace hell as your code would become

```
typedef unsigned char u8;

template <u8 N>
class matrix {
    public:
        matrix(std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> l);
    private:
        std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> arr;
};

template <u8 N>
matrix<N>::matrix(std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> l) : arr(l) {}


int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> arr{{{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}}}; // this is how you have to initialize a 2d std::array

    matrix<2> m = {{{{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}}}}; // we need one more brace here since we are initialzing the matrix, which needs its own brace
}
```