# how do I declare a 2d std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray

I want to use a 2d std::array as I've to use bound check at certain point in my program. For 1d array, I would do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main (){
  std::array<int,4> myarray;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
     myarray.at(i) = i+1;    
  }
}
```

How do I do it for a 2d array. Can I make use of auto in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array` is 1-dimensional, there is no such thing as a 2-dimensional `std::array`.  You would simply have to use an inner `std::array` as the element type of an outer `std::array`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(){
  std::array<std::array<int,5>,4> myarray;
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
      myarray[i].at(j) = j+1;    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To make this clearer, understand that a "2D array" is simply an "array-of-arrays".

Comment: @Remy Lebeau That answered my question. Can you also tell how do I initialize this->    `std::array <std::array<int,2>,2> myarray{{5,6},{7,8}};` . I'm getting a `too many initializers` error

Comment: @shoelace [Why can't simple initialize (with braces) 2D std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844475/)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main (){

    const size_t m = someInt;//the outer dim
    const size_t n = anotherOne;//the inner one

    std::array<std::array<int, m>, n> myArray;//it's an array containing m arrays
                                              // each one of them has n integers
    for( size_t i{}; i < m; ++i)  
        for (size_t j=0; j < n; j++){
            myarray[ i ] [ j ] = fillIt;    
        }
}
```

If u want to use an initializer list, you can use it as follows

```
std::array myArray{std::array{5,6},std::array{7,8}};//c++17
std::array<std::array<int, 2> > myArray{std::array<int, 2>{5,6},std::array<int, 2>{7,8}};
```

Note that the last initialization initializes the array with two temporary arrays each one of them has 2 `int` elements

Comment: is there a way to avoid typing `std::array` for all the inner arrays in the initializer list?