Create an array of div_t type structure elements in C++
I have a structure (this is kinda irrelevant for my question), and in this structure, a DATE type is used.
typedef div_t DATE;

#define ans         quot    /* (s)(l)div_t : .quot -> .ans...   */
#define mois        rem     /* ... et .rem -> .mois : plus parlant  */

DATE is of type div_t containing a year as quot and a month (mois) as rem. (... :) )
Anyhow.
I would like to make an array of elements for this DATA (div_t) type.
This seems to work as follows:
DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = {0, 0}; /* code testing  */

However, I don't know how to assign elements (year/quot, mois/rem) to this array:
This does not work:
    DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[0].quot = { 2026, 06 }; /* code testing  */
    DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[0].rem = { 2026, 06 }; /* code testing  */
    //DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1].ans = { 2026, 07 }; /* code testing  */
    //DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1].mois = { 2026, 07 }; /* code testing  */

    //DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2032, 06 }; /* code testing  */

Any idea how to create an array of "DATE"(s)/div_t elements and assign elements (quot, rem) to it?
I tried also this:
In the same .cpp file, I have these lines of code:
 double tx_tech_variable_vec[8] = { 0 }; 
 tx_tech_variable_vec[0] = 3.0;
 tx_tech_variable_vec[1] = 1.5;

 DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = { 0, 0 }; 
 DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2026, 07 };

with this error:

Line  Severity    Code    Description Project File    Suppression State
4680  Error   C2369   'tx_tech_variable_dates_vec': redefinition; different
subscripts

For tx_tech_variable_vec it seems to work fine, but not for DATE.
To reply to some comments:
Yes I know this is not the best way of doing it, but yes there are 90000 lines of code in the program I work with, that already use this DATE structure and this array way of working with things. So just to add a few lines of code, I will not introduce vectors or get rid of the macros or invent another DATE type that is not compatible with the rest of the (indeed very questionable) code.

You probably want to use a std::vector<div_t> instead of a c array and get rid of the typedef and macro usage completely.

This is C++, not "C".  So you would have "struct div_t { }"  and then std::vector<div_t> forget about all that nonsense with #define and typedefing struct. Maybe you should learn some C++ first,  Have a look at learncpp.com. I am not trying to be mean... but just telling you you're going the wrong direction ;)

Also for anything related to date/time use the classes from the <chrono> header file. E.g.  std::vector<std::chrono::year_month_day> there is no need for you to invent your own time structs

I added some info, for the understandable comments but I can't always take them into account giving the context I'm working in.

div_t is part of stdlib.h:
typedef struct _div_t
{
int quot;
int rem;
} div_t;

Side note: div_t, with its members quot and rem, is for division. You'd be better off defining your own struct to hold the data that you want (for example, struct DATE { int ans; int mois; };, or, as an earlier comment suggests, using stuff from <chrono>.

@pete Becker. Thx. Yes, you are right. But that's what the program uses and it's an ugly horse, but it's still running :). Won't start operating on it :). See last part of my question.

Assigning to an array element is no different from assigning to a non-array variable.  For instance tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[0] = { 2026, 06 }; would assign to the value { 2026, 06 } to the first element of tx_tech_variable_dates_vec.
Note that this is assignment though.  You're modifying the existing array element to match the value given.  It will have already been either zero-initialized or default-initialzed when the array was created (depending on how you initialized the array).

If you want to initialize the elements in tx_tech_variable_dates_vec when the array is created, then you can include initializers for the elements you want to initialize in the array's initializer.
For instance, the following will initialize the first three elements of tx_tech_variable_dates_vec with the given values:
DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = {
    { 2026, 06 }, { 2026, 12 }, { 2027, 03 }
};

Note that any elements you don't provide an initializer for will be zero-initialized.

Thanks, it actually works. I think I did not properly test it or had some other errors in the code that confused me. DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2026, 07 }; works perfectly :). Thx! I initialized the array like this: DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = {0, 0};

Actually, it does not work, in the same .cpp file, I have these lines of code:
 double tx_tech_variable_vec[8] = { 0 }; 
 tx_tech_variable_vec[0] = 3.0;
 tx_tech_variable_vec[1] = 1.5;

        DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = { 0, 0 }; // needed?
        DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2026, 07 };

with this error:
Line Severity Code Description Project File Suppression State
4680 Error C2369 'tx_tech_variable_dates_vec': redefinition; different subscripts
tx_tech_variable_vec seems to work
Ok, it's unreadable, I put it in the main question.

DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2026, 07 }; is attempting to define an array of one DATE named tx_tech_variable_dates_vec.  It's just like int var = 10;.  To assign to an element, remove the leading type name: tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2026, 07 };

Oh yes, a no brainer! Total noob here! Thx!

Little follow-up question, if you feel like it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78480062/assign-an-array-to-a-custom-made-structure?noredirect=1#comment138357293_78480062

Why would this give the error: too many initializers?
std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ { 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } };

std::array is actually a class that contains a c-style array, so you need an extra set of braces to initialize the inner array: std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{{ { 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } }};. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12844625/4151599.

Great. Actually now also this works: passing it to a custom structure via a pointer j. Before it wouldn't compile without the extra pair of {}.
j->tx_tech_variable_dates_vec_two = tx_tech_variable_dates_vec_two;
Thx!

It's ok, I don't need the leading zeros.
