Assign an array to a custom made structure
I have this code that assigns an array of 8 elements to a pointer that points to a instance j of a custom structure (Input_Leo).
In CFNN.cpp:
 {
     double tx_tech_variable_vec[8] = { 0 }; //I need this re-initialization // code testing:   variable rates on the initial premium payment of FIB/Invest Products with a time-variable garantueed interest rate */*/
     tx_tech_variable_vec[0] = 3.0; // it does not help to declare it in CFNN.H, as part of the InputLeo structure, you have to do it here before also
     tx_tech_variable_vec[1] = 1.5;
     DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = { 0, 0 }; // initialization
     tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[0] = { 2026, 07 };
     tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[1] = { 2032, 07 }; // assignment
     
     j->tx_tech_variable_vec = tx_tech_variable_vec; // overwrites everything (so for each contract (subcontract?), a new vector is written to j)
     j->tx_tech_variable_dates_vec = tx_tech_variable_dates_vec; // overwrites everything (so for each contract (subcontract?), a new vector is written to j)
 }

In CFNN.H:
struct Input_Leo /* input for Leo  */
{
    DATE calculation_date = { 2000, 0 };                    // Calculation date (used for RADP as date of the payment of unexpected premium)
    DATE   cohortmonthly = { 2000, 0 };                 //date payement prime conclusion (used in total business mode for the month of payment of yearly premiums, to know if we reached 12 months of historic of unex premiums)
    int lnumcon = 0;                            // Contract number
    int cregfsc = 0;                            

and so on...

  double* tx_tech = nullptr;                // pointer on Tx_res_LEO to allow for dynamic memory allocation, depending on the number of subcontracts
  double tx_tech_variable_vec[8] = {0};
DATE tx_tech_variable_dates_vec[8] = {0, 0}; /* code testing not sure I need to add it here */
    
};

I get this error:
Line    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Suppression State
4681    Error   C3863   array type 'double [8]' is not assignable   CF_2012_V7  C:\Users\U03630\Source\Repos\ctool\Main\code\CFNN.CPP   

Line    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Suppression State
4682    Error   C3863   array type 'DATE [8]' is not assignable CF_2012_V7  C:\Users\U03630\Source\Repos\ctool\Main\code\CFNN.CPP   

What am I doing wrong here? Should I specify the length of the array myself explicitly?
Also, the elements should be compatible with the DATE (div_t type). Will that still be the case if I work with std::array or std::vector?
Side note:
Yes I know this is not the best way of doing it, but yes there are 90000 lines of code in the program I work with, that already use this DATE structure and this array way of working with things. So just to add a few lines of code, I will not introduce vectors or get rid of the macros or invent another DATE type that is not compatible with the rest of the (indeed very questionable) code.


As the error mentions, C style arrays are not assignable.  Use C++ std::array if you want arrays with more sensible behavior.

Arrays are too stupid to assign. The reasons are best left to the 1970s. Use std::array instead.

Can you instead use std::vector<DATE> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec or std::array<DATE,8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec? This will add some ergonomic advantages instead of using C-style arrays

I might try that. I would be the only part of the 90000 lines of code/program that uses this type of arrays or vectors, but ok.

Side note: C++ is a language with a lot of legacy. Some of the stuff in it is pretty clunky and the language can be crazy complicated and nigh-impenetrable to guessing  based on how you'd use other languages. I strongly recommend a good book or two id you're going to do much with C++.

It's also pretty fast-moving. I don't write code the same way I did five years ago, let alone 10. (side note: I've been digging through C++ I wrote 15 years ago lately and I wrote really shitty c++ back then, even by the standards of the time) If you are maintaining an older program and using legacy build tools to do it, some of the stuff we suggest might not work. If std::array doesn't work, you'll have to std::copy or memcpy the array. std::copy is safer because it is conscious of what it copies. memcpy just moves bits, and with a complicated class, that can be fatal.

Thx, I should ask my employer to set some time aside for me to actually learn the language :D.

Using Visual Studio, and recently the code got "updated" to C++ (still 99% c syntax though).

At the very least, get your hands on a copy of Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers. When I'm training up a new hire, I hand them a copy of Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (second Ed) by Stroustrup and a copy of A Tour of C++ also by Stroustrup and show them where to find  Effective Modern C++ on the bookshelf. Principles and Practice  gets you up to C++14, and Tour patches thing up to C++20. The third edition of Principles and Practice just came out, so I might be down to needing one book. Have to get a copy and thumb through it before I start recommending it.

I should right. They don't care too much about training here, they just want to get the project done, somehow, setting some arbitrary deadline :).
But will have a look at your book recommendations.

C style arrays don't have a copy assignment operator, in C++ you can use std::array which has a copy assignment operator.
#include <array>

struct foo
{
    std::array<double,8> arr{}; // zero initialize
};

int main()
{
    foo a;
    std::array<double,8> b{0,1,2}; // init only first 3 elements
    a.arr = b; // all 8 elements copied, including the other value initialized 5 elements
}

you can still treat it like a C stye array using its .data() method, if you really need to pass around an unsafe double*
if you must use double[] because you are interfacing with C code then you can use std::copy to copy elements and std::fill to fill elements (for example zero initialization).
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

struct foo
{
    double arr[8];  // struct is used in C code
};

int main()
{
    foo a;
    // fill array with zeros
    std::fill(std::begin(a.arr), std::end(a.arr),0);

    double arr2[8] = {1,2,3};
    // copy from arr2 to a.arr
    std::copy(std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2), std::begin(a.arr));
}


Thx! But I should still initialize this std::array in my Input_Leo structure (cfnn.h), as well as in the CFNN.cpp file, I guess?

@babipsylon if you zero initialize it in the header with arr{} then by default it will be zero initialized, you can override this behavior in the constructor by using a member initializer lists if for example one constructor needs to fill it using values from the parameters.

I see, you re-initialize in the main function:
std::array<double,8> b{0,1,2}; // init only first 3 elements
and assign the first 3 elements (within the initialization).

@babipsylon "you re-initialize in the main function" - there is no such thing as "re-initialization". Initialization is a one time thing - you may assign later, but that's not the same as initializing.

The same should work for an array of div_t type I guess, with an array of elements {quot, rem}?

@babipsylon yes, that's a trivial copyable type, so an array of it is also copyable, std::array is copyable if its elements are copyable, a non-copyable type is something like std::unique_ptr or atomics and mutexes.

I see. It seems not to compile though. (DATE, here, is, in fact, just a div_t type):
std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ { 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } };
j->tx_tech_variable_vec = tx_tech_variable_dates_vec;
with
typedef div_t DATE;
std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ { 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } };
j->tx_tech_variable_vec = tx_tech_variable_dates_vec;

@babipsylon std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ { 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } } the compiler cannot deduce the inner type, you need to specify it at least for the first element std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ DATE{ 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } } because that is aggregate initialization

Thx, that works. It only skips to the next error though when assigning to a structure:
j->tx_tech_variable_vec = tx_tech_variable_dates_vec;
4685 Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::array<DATE,8>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

@babipsylon both right and left hand sides of the assignment should have the same type, do they ? if they are not exactly the same type then you need to use the std::copy as shown in the answer.

I see. In the structure that j points too (Input_Leo), I have put this:
std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{};  // testing
So I guess that's the same type?

Actually, the specification of the inner type DATE did not solve all problems: 1) yes it compiles now 2) all the elements of this array of div_t (DATE) stays initialized at some default values (-858993460), even after running that line.
std::array<DATE, 8> tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ DATE{ 2032, 05 },{ 2026, 06 } }

@babipsylon it is working with almost any modern c++ compiler as per this example https://godbolt.org/z/6Ea3WMTcx how different is your code from that example ? Also what version of the compiler you are using ?

Hmmm, ok.
I think I need to provide you with these values:
Project (right-click your project name in solution explorer) > Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard
I'm using:
ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)
ISO C11 Standard (/std:c11)
Does that explain anything?
It seems to me my code is not any different from your example. However in your example with the link, I don't know how to check the contents of the array of div_t created there.

@babipsylon Is the file named something.c or something.cpp ? The compiler treats the code as C or C++ based on extension so the file name should end with .cpp otherwise you cannot use C++ functionality.

It has the .cpp extension.
This is the exact code:
std::array<DATE, 8> current_tx_tech_variable_dates_vec{ DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2026,06}, DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2032,05}, DATE{2032,05} };
I copy pasted the watch window into the main question.

@babipsylon i though the code wasn't compiling, is the problem that the rest of the values are garbage ? The assignment operator copies the entire thing, even the garbage uninitialized values, if you only want to copy the first 3 then also use std::copy using arr.begin()+3 for the end value, std::array has the same behavior of C arrays where the uninitialized values are garbage.

The code didn't want to compile when I didn't specify the inner type (DATE). Now it compiles, but the problem is that it does not change/assigns the values to the desired values (e.g.) {2032,05}. At the line of initialization, where now 8 values are passed, it gets executed, but as you can see in the screenshot of the watch window, all values are just some (random?) values and do not change to the desired values.
