# Array of Object - std::array - Constructor Initialization Problems

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm writing a periodic table program to help me understand classes. 
I want to be able to display/sort the elements by several properties such as whether it's a metal, nonmetal, or metalloid. I'm not sure hwo to do it, but my first guess was to create an array of objects; however, I'm having problems using my constructor to set the values.

**Class**

```
class Element{
    public:
       enum class groupNames {  HYDROGEN, ALKALI, ALKALINE, GROUP_THREE, GROUP_FOUR, GROUP_FIVE,
                                GROUP_SIX, GROUP_SEVEN, GROUP_EIGHT, GROUP_NINE, GROUP_TEN,
                                GROUP_ELEVEN,GROUP_TWELVE, GROUP_THIRTEEN, GROUP_FOURTEEN,
                                GROUP_FIFTEEN, CHALCOGEN, HALOGEN, NOBLE_GAS
                                };
        enum class orbitals {ORBITAL_NOTSET, S_BLOCK, P_BLOCK, D_BLOCK, F_BLOCK};
        enum class metal_status {METAL = 0, METALLOID, NONMETAL};
        Element();
        Element(int aNumber, int pNumber,groupNames groupnames, metal_status MetalStatus, orbitals Orbital,std::string eName, std::string eSybol);
        void displayProperties();

    private:
        groupNames groupNumber;
        orbitals orbital;
        metal_status metalStatus;
        std::string elementSymbol;
        std::string elementName;
        int atomicNumber;
        int periodNumber;
};

Element::Element()
{
    atomicNumber = 0;
    periodNumber = 0;
    groupNumber = groupNames::HYDROGEN;
    metalStatus = metal_status::METAL;
    orbital = orbitals::ORBITAL_NOTSET;
    elementName = "NULL";
    elementSymbol = "NULL";
}

Element::Element(int aNumber, int pNumber,groupNames groupnames, metal_status MetalStatus, orbitals Orbital,std::string eName, std::string eSymbol)
{
    groupNumber = groupnames;
    metalStatus = MetalStatus;
    orbital = Orbital;
    atomicNumber = aNumber;
    periodNumber = pNumber;
    elementName = eName;
    elementSymbol = eSymbol;
}

void Element::displayProperties()
{
    std::cout << elementName << ", " << elementSymbol << "\n"
              << "Group Number: " << as_integer(groupNumber) << "\n"
              << "Metal Status: " << as_integer(metalStatus) << "\n"
              << "Orbital: "      << as_integer(orbital) << "\n"
              << "Atomic Number: "<< atomicNumber << "\n"
              << "Period Number: "<< periodNumber;
}
```

**Previous Method of Initialization** //Works fine, the problem is I can't sort by properties

```
Element Hydrogen(1,1, Element::groupNames::HYDROGEN, Element::metal_status::NONMETAL, Element::orbitals::S_BLOCK, "Hydrogen", "H");
Element Helium(2, 1, Element::groupNames::NOBLE_GAS, Element::metal_status::NONMETAL, Element::orbitals::S_BLOCK, "Helium", "He");
```

**std::array Method -- Problem!**

```
std::array<Element, 115> Elements =
{
    Elements[0],
    Elements[1](1,1, Element::groupNames::HYDROGEN, Element::metal_status::NONMETAL, Element::orbitals::S_BLOCK, "Hydrogen", "H")
};
```

> **Error:** error: no match for call to '(std::array::value_type {aka Element}) (int, int, Element::groupNames,
>   Element::metal_status, Element::orbitals, const char [9], const char
>   [2])'

Comment: You seem to be using elements of an uninitialized `std::array` in the initialization of said array.

Comment: Crysis - for others (and if I'm not mistaken) - can you correct the code to remove referencing the uninitialized array inside the initialization list?  Also, minor point, but the `enum` is actually named `groupNames` in your code, but you refer to it as `group` - like I say, minor point, but it's nice to not have questions with erroneous code.

Comment: I can change the group. I have a typeset set up, and I didn't change that when it as added here. As far as the array, that was part of the problem; I don't see why I should correct the code in my question when it'll lead to confusion for those that may later come across this. I also may be misunderstanding you, I've had 4 hours of sleep these past two nights because of A.P. classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need two sets of braces (I was pulling my hair out figuring out what clang was complaining about.) I suggest uniform initialization. Also, I prefixed your enums with `Element` for qualification and changed them to match what their names are in your class definition.

```
std::array<Element, 115> Elements =
{{
    {},
    {1,1, Element::groupNames::HYDROGEN, Element::metal_status::NONMETAL, Element::orbitals::S_ORBITAL, "Hydrogen", "H"}
}};
```

---

Alternatively, you can try:

```
std::array<Element, 115> Elements
{  
  Element(), 
  Element(1,1, Element::groupNames::HYDROGEN, Element::metal_status::NONMETAL, Element::orbitals::S_ORBITAL, "Hydrogen", "H")  
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to try this out. I have a typedef set up; that's why my code says group:: and metalStat::.

Comment: @Crysis Also, you can replace `as_integer` with `static_cast<int>`, as an `enum class`'s underlying type is `int` by default.

Comment: I'm new to uniform initialization - can you explain why the two sets of curly braces are necessary?

Comment: @remyabel I was trying to figure that out, but I forgot about staic casts, so I used this: `template <typename Enumeration>
auto as_integer(Enumeration const value)
    -> typename std::underlying_type<Enumeration>::type
{
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enumeration>::type>(value);
}`

Comment: Thanks. Also, I have the same question as @DanNissenbaum

Comment: @Dan See [c++ why initializer_list behavior for std::vector and std::array are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/c-why-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-are-different) and other similar questions. In certain cases, the second set of braces can be elided, but in this case, they can't.

Comment: @remyabel Thanks for the link, and answer. I thought about using an array, but I have no need for this array to grow.

Comment: To summarize the link, both to make certain I have it right and for others reading this (if I am right), the `{ {...} }` (double-curly-brace) syntax must be used due to the current requirement (which may be considered a defect and removed) that when the `=` is used for initialization, *only one object* may appear between the (single) curly braces to the right.  In order to work around this, the second set of curly braces makes the list appear as a *single* object (namely, a list object).