# How to create a 2D vector array with default values?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I create an NxM 2D int vector and create default values for it?

Here I try to create a 3x3 int vector with some values:

```
vector< vector<int> > m(3, vector<int> (3)) = {
    {1,2,9},
    {8,4,7},
    {5,6,0}
   };
```

But this errors with

```
> g++ a.cpp -std=c++11

error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
     vector< vector<int> > m(3, vector<int> (3)) = {
                                                 ^
error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
```

I am using c++11 also, so shouldn't the above syntax be correct? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235141/7285967), it should be okay?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  get rid of the constructor call since the initializer list replaces that.  `vector< vector<int> > m = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you remove what's in the parenthesis. The dimensions are determined by the size of the initializer lists. If you want to specify the size yourself, you can use `std::array`.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > m= {
    {1,2,9},
    {8,4,7},
    {5,6,0}
   };
```

Initializing arrays is a bit different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/why-is-the-c-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-differen). You need double braces.

```
#include <array>
std::array< std::array<int, 3>, 3 > m= {{
    {1,2,9},
    {8,4,7},
    {5,6,0}
    }};
```

Comment: What is the difference between using `std::array` and `std::vector` when declaring a 2D array? When would you use one over the other?

Comment: @vuvume The size of an `std::array` is specified at compile time and can never change. The size of an `std::vector` can change at runtime.

Comment: Is using `std::array` the same as doing `int m[3][3]`?

Comment: @vuvume No, `std::array` is different from c arrays like `int m[3][3];`. `std::array` is a class much like `std::vector`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not really.  A `std::array` is just a wrapper for `T[]`.  It has the same aggregate initialization.  It just adds some convenience functions and makes passing the array "easier".  Yes it is a class type but it really is basically a drop in replacement or `T[]`

Comment: If I do `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> arr = {{},{},{}};`, is it valid to check `arr[2][2] == null`? If not, how would I check for null elements?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm just trying to avoid any confusion where @vuvume would interpret my comment as recommending `int m[3][3]`.

Comment: @vuvume That is fine since any missing initializer is turned into a zero initializer.

Comment: @vuvume: What book are you using? The Stack Overflow comments section is not the proper place to learn C++.

Comment: @vuvume, there are _no_ null elements in an empty data container, and accessing a nonexistent element will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The code in parentheses provides arguments for `vector`'s constructor:

```
vector<vector<int>>(3, vector<int>(3));
```

This creates a new vector that contains three elements of type `vector`, and each of them has got three integers inside. So, *no `null`s inside a vector in this case*.

This code:

```
vector<vector<int>> test = 
    { {3,4,5},
       {4,5,6} };
```

Uses another constructor, which takes an *initializer list* and deduces the size of the resulting vector by itself.

*Those are different constructors!* When you construct an object with the `Type object(arg1, arg2);` notation, you're basically calling the constructor of `Type`. You're *calling a function*, and of course you cannot adding to a function call.

Comment: What if I want to initialize an empty 3x3 array? How would I access `test[2][2] == null`?

Comment: @vuvume: `null`?? Stop randomly guessing - programming doesn't work that way. Anyway, there is no such thing as an empty 3x3 array; an array either has elements, or it doesn't.