# initialize an array of compile-time constant size with incrementing numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an array whose size is set using a compile-time constant (a pre-processor `#define` in my case). I need to initialize it using consecutive numbers at compile-time. How can I do this?

Simplified example:

```
#define ARR_SZ 5
struct C {
  C(int a) : a(a) {}
  int a;
};
C arr[ARR_SZ] = {{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}}; // This needs to adapt to any number
```

I can use C++11, but not newer (although I would be interested to learn of newer techniques even if I can't use them for this project)

Comment: Can it be `std::array` instead of a raw array?

Comment: [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)?

Comment: `std::make_index_sequence` (C++14) (can be implemented in C++11).

Comment: @StoryTeller In the actual code it is an `std::array`, as well as being of a class type with no default constructor and only a constructor that accepts an integer. I was trying to simplify

Comment: The use of a class without a default constructor could make a big difference. Always try to create a [mcve] to show us, don't simplify to much.

Comment: The answers in the "duplicate" question are about assigning to an array after it was created. I need to initialize it at deceleration

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Baruch: Are you allowed to use Boost?

Comment: @P.W No, but out of curiosity, what does Boost have to offer here?

Comment: @Baruch: If the number of elements are decided at compile time then not much difference between vector and array.

Comment: @P.W No, this is an embedded system with no dynamic allocation allowed or even supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 code (because of `std::integer_sequence`):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

#define ARR_SZ 5
struct C {
  C(int a) : a(a) {}
  int a;
};

template<int ...Is>
auto make_C_arr(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) -> std::array<C, sizeof...(Is)> {
    return {{ {Is}... }};
}

auto arr = make_C_arr(std::make_integer_sequence<int, ARR_SZ>{});

int main () {

}
```

`std::integer_sequence` and the like are implementable in C++11 however as noted in a comment, so substituting the standard version for a home-brewed one will give a C++11 specific solution.

Comment: Can this be done without the extra function call (`make_C_arr`)? It just looks ugly

Comment: @Baruch - No. Not this. Something needs to unpack. You can try the preprocessor instead if you prefer.

Comment: Why is the double-bracket needed? (`{{ {Is}.. }}` instead of `{ {Is}.. }`)

Comment: @Baruch - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/why-is-the-c-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-differen

Answer (score 1):

Since boost was mentioned in the comment section, here's another totally different solution based on Boost.PP. It's also entirely C++03.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>

#define ARR_SZ 5
struct C {
  C(int a) : a(a) {}
  int a;
};

#define INIT(z, n, d) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) C(n)

C arr[ARR_SZ] = { BOOST_PP_REPEAT(ARR_SZ, INIT, ?) };


int main () {

}
```

`BOOST_PP_REPEAT` will expand to `INIT(z, 0, ?) ... INIT(z, 4, ?)`. The `z` is not relevant to our goal, and the `?` token is just a placeholder. Since `INIT` in turn expands to `C(n)` for `n` from 0 to 4 (comma delimited), we get an initializer for a regular C style array.