# Initialize array whose size is a compile-time constant to single value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a c-style array whose size is defined by a `#define` and can change based on compiling options, e.g.

```
#if LINUX
# define SIZE 4
#else
# define SIZE 5
#endif
static int myArr[SIZE] = { /* ??? */ };
```

How can I initialize the whole array to a non-zero value, for example all `42`?

Comment: @SamerTufail: memset is runtime, OP searches for compile time I be leave!

Comment: Is `#define V 42` `#define INIT4   V, V, V, V` `#define INIT6   INIT4 , V, V` and then placing `#define INIT <XXX>` in those `#ifelses` too dumb? With `static int myArr[] = { INIT};` It's not so pretty, but it get's the job done.

Comment: Is switching to a `std::array` an option?

Comment: And how about using a library like [Boost.PP](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html)?

Comment: I thought I had a sense of deja vu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286610/initialize-an-array-of-compile-time-constant-size-with-incrementing-numbers

Comment: @StoryTeller I had completely forgotten that I had asked this already! <embarrassed>. Although they are not completely the same question (there I needed consecutive numbers, here I need the same number), the answer from there can probably be adapted

Answer (score 8):

I don't know a solution for C-style arrays, though with `constexpr` and C++17 you could do this with `std::array`.

```
constexpr std::array<int, SIZE> createFilledArray (int value){
   std::array<int, SIZE> a{0};
   for (auto i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
       a[i] = value;
   return a;
}

static constexpr auto myArr = createFilledArray(42);
```

[Code at compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/p760Cb)

The disadvantage of this is that you can't change the array.
If you remove the `constexpr` from the variable, your compiler should be able to optimize this.

From C++20 on, you can force the initialization:

```
static constinit auto myArr = createFilledArray(42);
```

Not sure if the proposal is already merged in: see [constinit proposal](https://gist.github.com/EricWF/128781c188b1a4fca7581e7ea943d58b)

Comment: The loop in your `createFilledArray()`  can be replaced with `a.fill(value)`.

Comment: [std::array::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) is only declared constexpr in C++20

Comment: I need C++11 (as noted by the question tags)

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on builtin arrays, you can use static variables in functions:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto arr_helper2(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> int (&)[N]
{
    static int arr[N] = {((void)Is, 42)...};
    return arr;
}

template <std::size_t N>
auto arr_helper() -> int (&)[N]
{
    return arr_helper2<N>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

static int (&arr)[SIZE] = arr_helper<SIZE>();
```

For example:

```
int main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UJ7Sn3HE3wNR1t98)

Answer (score 0):

For the poor souls who are still limited to C++14, here's a C++14 solution that allows you to fill the C array according to a function `fill`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int SIZE = 5;
constexpr int fill(std::size_t index){ return 42; }

template <int INDEX = 0, int... Values>
struct Helper : Helper<INDEX + 1, Values..., fill(INDEX)> {};

template <int... Values>
struct Helper<SIZE, Values...>{
    static constexpr int table[SIZE] = { Values... };
};

template <int... Values>
constexpr int Helper<SIZE, Values...>::table[SIZE];

int main() {
    auto constexpr arr = Helper<0>::table;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

However, note that this only works for integral types.