# Initialize an std::array algorithmically at compile time

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, compile-time, stdarray

Consider:

```
static constexpr unsigned num_points{ 7810 };
std::array< double, num_points > axis;

for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i)
{
    axis[i] = 180 + 0.1 * i;
}
```

`axis` is a class-wide constant. I want to avoid initializing it like any other global variable. Can it be done at compile time?

---

This is the final class in its entirety:

```
// https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-compendium-basic-ideas-notation-data-and-formulas/atomic-spectroscopy
// https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database
struct Spectrum
{
    static constexpr unsigned _num_points{ 7810 };
    using Axis = std::array< double, _num_points >;

    static constexpr Axis _x{ [] ()            // wavelength, nm
        {
            Axis a {};
            for( unsigned i = 0; i < _num_points; ++i )
            {
                a[ i ] = 180 + 0.1 * i;
            }
            return a;
        } () };
    Axis _y {};                                // radiance, W·sr−1·m−2
};
```

The mixing of code and variables is unsightly, but at least the formula is right in front of the reader's eyes. Any other solution involved a lot of typing in order to get the in-class defined constant and type.

Or if I change my heart, I can simply return the lambda at runtime.

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376301/2466431

Comment: If your data is really read-only with this pattern, for *most* use cases on most hardware you're better off computing it at runtime.  7810 * 8 bytes is a big cache footprint for the array.  Loading a base + scale factor is only 2 doubles = 16 bytes.  Computing at runtime is cheap: one int->FP conversion, and one FMA or a mul + add.  (Plus loading the constants).  So yes on a cache hit the LUT is faster, but especially for repeated use inside a loop just computing is often going to be good.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For completeness' sake, here's a version that does not require the definition of a function but instead uses a lambda. C++17 introduced the ability of using lambdas in constant expressions, so you can declare your array `constexpr` and use a lambda to initialize it:

```
static constexpr auto axis = [] {
    std::array<double, num_points> a{};
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) {
        a[i] = 180 + 0.1 * i;
    }
    return a;
}();
```

(Note the `()` in the last line, which calls the lambda right away.)

If you don't like the `auto` in the `axis` declaration because it makes it harder to read the actual type, but you don't want to repeat the type inside the lambda, you can instead do:

```
static constexpr std::array<double, num_points> axis = [] {
    auto a = decltype(axis){};
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) {
        a[i] = 180 + 0.1 * i;
    }
    return a;
}();
```

Comment: You don't need the `constexpr` in the lambda :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 You are right. The lambda's call operator is marked `constexpr` automatically.

Answer (score 32):

Here is the full compileable code:

```
#include <array>

template<int num_points>
static constexpr std::array<double, num_points> init_axis() {
    std::array<double, num_points> a{};
    for(int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) 
    {
        a[i] = 180 + 0.1 * i;
    }
    return a;
};

struct Z {
    static constexpr int num_points = 10;
    static constexpr auto axis = init_axis<num_points>();
};
```

Comment: Suggest substituting `std::array<double,num_points>` for `auto` so the reader doesn't have to check the initializing function to know the type.

Comment: @doug I find it to be the matter of preference. Some people like to know the type, some people prefer less `type`ing (pun natural!).

Comment: I prefer auto too, for the same reason. But when the type isn't obvious for someone reading the line of code, including me a month later, I'll put in the extra typing. Probably helpful for readers coming to the question as well.

Comment: @doug your code editor doesn't give you the type and doesn't allow you to jump to function in a single click?

Comment: Of course. But when just scanning a screen of code it doesn't. Have to put the cursor on the variable. I prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 16):

There's also the `std::index_sequence` trick ([<kbd>Wandbox example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VZOxbzxg5gceOAZ4)):

```
template <unsigned... i>
static constexpr auto init_axis(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, i...>) {
   return std::array{(180 + 0.1 * i)...};
};

static constexpr auto axis = init_axis(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, num_points>{});
```

Comment: is this possible with c++14?

Comment: @jp94 Yes. The only part that isn't in C++14 is CTAD: https://wandbox.org/permlink/q9aolw8WgWr0tFRF